# How do I find all the classes used in a PHP file?

Tags: php, class, code-analysis, tokenize

I am trying to use the tokenizer to scan a file to find all the defined classes, anything they extend, any created instances, and anytime they were statically invoked.

```
<?php

$tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents($file));

$used_classes = array();
$defined_classes = array();
$variable_classes = array();

foreach($tokens as $i => $token) {

    if(is_array($token)) {

        if(isset($tokens[$i - 2][0], $tokens[$i - 1][0])) {

            // new [class]
            if ($tokens[$i - 2][0] == T_NEW AND $tokens[$i - 1][0] == T_WHITESPACE) {

                if($tokens[$i][0] == T_STRING) {
                    $used_classes[$token[1]] = TRUE;

                // new $variable()
                } elseif($tokens[$i][0] == T_VARIABLE) {    

                    // @todo, this is really broken. However, do best to look for the assignment
                    if(preg_match('~\$var\s*=\s*([\'"])((?:(?!\1).)*)\1~', $text, $match)) {
                        if(empty($extension_classes[$match[2]])) {
                            $used_classes[$match[2]] = TRUE;
                        }
                    } elseif($token[1] !== '$this') {
                        $variable_classes[$token[1]] = TRUE;
                    }
                }

            }

            // class [class]
            if ($tokens[$i - 2][0] == T_CLASS AND $tokens[$i - 1][0] == T_WHITESPACE) {

                if($tokens[$i][0] == T_STRING) {
                    $defined_classes[$token[1]] = TRUE;
                }
            }


            // @todo: find more classes \/

            // class [classname] extends [class] ???
            // [class]::method()???
        }
    }
}
```

How can I extend this code to find any additional instances of PHP classes like mentioned above?

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php
- http://westhoffswelt.de/blog/class_dependency_graph_generation_update.html
- http://phpqatools.org/

Comment: There is magic constant __ FILE __ (with no spaces) in PHP. You can open (fopen or file_get_contents) this file and search it via preg_match (something like /^\s*class(.*)$/ and /(.*)::(.*)/ and so). Know that quite not-straigh solution so maybe someone will found a better one. If you want to find all classes, you can use function get_declared_classes (http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php) and so, but remember, that also core classes will be included.

Comment: Out of your three recommendations, only searching with regex has anything to do with static analysis of PHP code. However, I would rather avoid regex since the PHP parser is more trust-worthy. I also can't imagine how complex the regex would have to be to find a variable variable.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid that full filling you request (finding class definition and calls in target file) is not possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing and then interpreting PHP code is not something that can be solved well using a regex. You would need a something much more clever, like a state machine, that can actually understand things like scope, class names, inheritance etc to be able to do what you want.

It just so happens, that I happen to have written a [PHP-to-Javascript](https://github.com/Danack/PHP-to-Javascript) converter based on a state-machine that will almost do most of what you want to do:

> all the defined classes

Yes, all the classes create a ClassScope with all their variables listed and their methods are created as FunctionScope's, so you can tell which methods a class has.

> anything they extend

Yes, every class has it's parent classes listed in ClassScope->$parentClasses

> any created instances

Nope, but wouldn't be hard to add extra code to record these.

> anytime they were statically invoked.

Nope - but that actually could be done with a regex.

Although it doesn't exactly solve your problem, the project as it stands would get you 95% of the way towards what you want to do, which would save a couple weeks work.

Answer (score 0):

[Inclued](http://pecl.php.net/package/inclued) is probably worth looking into here, though I don't think it will provide you with any data beyond which files/classes were included and how many times.

Comment: That's a good tool to know about, but unfortunately it requires that you run the code. I'm looking for static analysis since it's not realistic to run every aspect of a PHP system which does not contain full code-coverage from unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this by just analyzing tokens.

You need to know, for any class name, what actual definition it represents, including any inheritance relations, and whether it has been used in your code to implement an interface.  The class/interface definition may be in another file; that file may be included under some condition. You may have the same class name defined differently in different files.  So in general you need to to process all the files that comprise your system at once.

What you need as a foundation is a tool that parses PHP and builds up real symbol tables.  You might be able to compute your result from that.  (Such a tool analyzes tokens as a starting place, but it is far more work than trivial token scanning).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you just load the code, you can then use the built-in Reflection API ([ReflectionClass::_construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.construct.php), etc.) to examine each class.

To get the classes themselves, use the built-in [get_declared_classes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php).

*(Note: I have not tried this, so YMMV.)*

Comment: This isn't really acceptable, however, perhaps I could fork a process and load the file (even if it trashes everything) and return the new functions/classes found.